# Word for something said 'too soon'

Tags: single-word-requests

When something someone says is 'too soon' or relating to a matter that shouldn't be talked about lightly (like joking about a recent terrorist attack or natural disaster), what is the offensive joke or phrase called?

I'm aware that this could simply be called an offensive joke, but I'd like something more specific, something would address this scenario in particular.

Comment: "Poor taste" is another term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can describe a joke or comment said at an inappropriate time as **untactful**.

---

I always like including definitions for words I provide in answers, however, when I searched for a good definition of "untactful", all I found were [circular definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_definition) like:

> **untactful**
>   not having or showing tact

I therefore am also including the [Oxford definition of "tactful"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tactful):

> **tactful**
>   Having or showing skill and sensitivity in dealing with others or with difficult issues.

Since "untactful" is the opposite of "tactful", you can conclude that "untactful" can be used to describe actions that do not show sensitivity in dealing with others or with issues.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the word you're looking for, but 'inconsiderate' would work.

Answer (score 0):

pre·ma·ture

> : happening too soon or earlier than usual
>   : born before the normal time
>   Full Definition
>   : happening, arriving, existing, or performed before the proper, usual, or intended time; especially : born after a gestation period of less than 37 weeks 
>   premature noun
>   pre·ma·ture·ly adverb
>   pre·ma·ture·ness noun
>   pre·ma·tu·ri·ty-ˈtyu̇r-ə-tē, -ˈtu̇r-, -